# How can we check if the elements consist a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We consider the elements of the form $\langle a, \varnothing \rangle$, where $a$ is a set.

How can we check if the elements of the form $\langle a, \varnothing \rangle$ consist a set?

Could you give me some hints?

Comment: What does $\langle \cdot \rangle$ indicate?

Comment: @GFauxPas It isn't given any further infomartion... :/

Comment: What kind of book or document did you find it in? Maybe it's on the previous pages?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $\langle ~,~\rangle$ means an ordered pair.

**No**, in standard set theory there is no set which has everything of the form $\langle A,\varnothing\rangle$ as elements.

Namely, if such a thing existed -- let's call it $X$ -- we could make a variant of Russell's paradox, by considering the subset
$$ Y = \{ \langle A,B\rangle \in X \mid \langle A,B\rangle \notin A \} $$
Now $\langle Y,\varnothing\rangle$ is in $Y$ if and only if $\langle Y,\varnothing\rangle$ isn't in $Y$, which is impossible. So $X$ cannot have existed.

---

Alternatively, if we're using Kuratowski pairs, we can also just say that $\bigcup \bigcup X$ would be a set of all sets, which is known to be impossible by the standard Russell paradox.

Comment: I feel like given the "elementary set theory" tag that it's unlikely that they mean anything beyond the same as "{". I've encountered that notation in a few places before.

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman: Ordered pairs are completely within the scope of elementary-set-theory. It's not restricted to _naive_ set theory.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are defined by their elements. If you list out the elements, it immediately forms a set from the rules of ZFC (which is the axiomatic definition of how one can construct sets). This also works for infinite cases, for example, $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ defines a set as well, with the minor counterexample of exceptionally large classes of objects (there is a sense in which things can be "too big" to be a set, but that's not going to be relevent at your level, only mentioned for completeness)

Comment: Joshua Biderman So, is $\langle a, \varnothing \rangle$ a set, since both $a$ and $\varnothing$ are sets?

Comment: No, because we (from what you've said) have no reason to think that $a$ is a set. It is a set because $a$ and $\emptyset$ are things.

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman: How don't you think that the words "where $a$ is a set" in the question is a reason to think $a$ is a set?

Comment: Because I missed that. Yes, any collection of sets of reasonable size is a set. "Reasonable" here is a bit hard to define in an elementary sense, but again, that's a technical note not likely to be too relevant yet. If you ever need to prove a collection, $C$, is a set, the easiest way is to demonstrate a set that's larger than it.